# Why do configuration spaces not form an operad?

Tags: algebraic-topology, operads

I have seen in multiple sources that the collection of configuration spaces $\{Conf(n,m)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where
$$Conf(n,m)=\{(x_1, \ldots ,x_n) \in (\mathbb{R}^m)^n | x_i \neq x_j \text{ if } i \neq j\}$$
do not form an operad, (I think this can be stated where we consider configurations in any manifold $M$ rather than necessarily a space $\mathbb{R}^m$, but I have stuck with euclidean vector spaces for now). Does anyone know of a resource where this is proved or could in fact give a proof that it is indeed impossible to create such an operad?

Comment: Certainly there is an operad whose components are homotopy equivalent to these spaces, namely the little disks operad. That's good enough for me.

Comment: I am aware of that, there is also the operad made up from compactifications of configuration spaces which is an object I am particularly interested in. However I would like to be able to justify why we have to use these compactifications rather than just the configuration spaces themselves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am not sure that it is "good enough". Even if $P(r) \sim Q(r)$ for all arities $r$, finding a weak equivalence $P \leftarrow \cdot \to Q$ is not always a trivial task, and may even prove impossible... Meaning the operads really encode different structures. Writing down a weak equivalence between the little cubes operad and the little disks one is not so easy, for example. The problem may be more evident in the realm of dg-modules; formality of operads is a huge topic.

Comment: To continue my comment, here's a silly but somewhat shocking example: if $\mathtt{Ass}$ is the symmetric operad for associative algebras and $\mathtt{Pois}$ the one for Poisson algebras, then in characteristic zero, for all $n$ the $\Sigma_n$-modules $\mathtt{Ass}(n)$ and $\mathtt{Pois}(n)$ are isomorphic! (PBW) But of course there is no weak equivalence (say, of dg-modules) between $\mathtt{Ass}$ and $\mathtt{Pois}$...